# Can both US Senators from a state be elected at the same time?

Tags: united-states, election, constitution, senate

I understand the US constitution mandates three rolling 'classes' of nearly equal numbers of Senators be elected every two years, each for 6 year terms.  The convention has been to not elect both Senators from a state in the same 'class' ie always at the same time.  Could a state decide to elect them in the same class though?

As a follow up, could a state elect both Senators not just on the same ballot but in the same race.  Electing the two candidates with the highest votes.

Answer (score 27):

Each senator is in one of three classes, and at each election all the senators in one class are elected. In the 2018 race, for example the "class 1" senators were elected. That regular elections for different classes happen at different dates is not merely a convention, it is mandated by Article one of the Constitution.

In addition to the regular elections that choose senators for a period of six years, and are held every two years (as mandated by Article 1, as modified by Amendment 17), there are also "special elections". These occur when a senator dies, resigns or is otherwise removed from office. Special elections can be held at any time. The senator elected in a special election serves only for the remainder of the term. So if senator dies two years into their 6 year term and is replaced in a special election, the new senator may serve for the remaining four years before having to face re-electionn

It is possible for special elections for a Senate seat to be scheduled on the same day as regular elections. In which case a single ballot paper can be used for the two Senate seats (and the House seat, and any other elections occurring at the same time) This saves money and is convenient.

For example in 2018, in Minnesota, Tina Smith was elected to fill the class 2 Senate seat in a special election, while, at the same time, Amy Klobuchar was elected to the class 1 seat. Klobuchar will now serve for 6 years, while Smith will face re-election in two years time in the class two senate elections.

The constitution is allows states to organise the election as they see fit. It only requires that:

> When vacancies happen in the representation of any State in the Senate, the executive authority of such State shall issue writs of election to fill such vacancies.

This would seem to require that a separate election is held for the vacant seat. At any rate, there is little to gain in holding a joint election. It creates a confusing system in which the parties would game the system, entering 1 or 2 candidates according to tactics and reducing the ability of the electorate to choose their senators. No state has done this.

Comment: How does "for example in 2018 in Minnesota" square with "no state has done this"?

Comment: @Henning As far as I understand, no state has done a joint election; but some (as in Minessota in 2018) have done two separate elections in the same day.

Comment: Is it technically possible for states to change the classes of their senators (e.g. move both Alabama senators to class 2 and both Alaska senators to class 3)? If yes, then who has a privilege to do so?

Comment: @defaultlocale No, it looks like classes are assigned by the Senate itself (by lot, when necessary). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classes_of_United_States_Senators

Comment: @AzorAhai But doesn't it mean that the Senate, as a whole, has the power to reassign classes as long as they don't break "as equally as may be" clause? The whole scenario is purely hypothetical and kinda impractical, but as far as I understand, the Senate can do this without violating the Constitution.

Comment: @defaultlocale Your question was whether *states* can unilaterally reassign their senators. My answer was that they can't. As for your new question, I have no idea whether the Senate can reassign classes, but I suspect not, as that would necessarily change the length of some Senators terms to something other than six, something I would suggest would be unconstitutional.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mississippi also had elections for both of its Senate seats in 2018. The special election is now going for a run-off, as no candidate received 50% of the vote and Mississippi law requires a run-off election in that event.

Comment: _"That elections for different classes happen at different dates is mandated by the Constitution."_ and _"It is possible for special elections for a senate seat to be scheduled on the same day as regular elections."_ -- Well, isn't that a contradiction? Should the first say "regular elections", or something like that? And then the follow-up that comes to mind is if it would be possible to have the regular elections on three consecutive weeks... what sets the two-year interval anyway?

Comment: @ilkkachu There's no contradiction. You are imagining that "regular elections" and "special elections" are two kinds of "election". The actual situation is that there are two things, one called an "election" and another called a "special election".

Comment: @LordHieros: "two separate elections in the same day" seems to be meaningless.  There's one election, with two separate Senate seats to be filled - just as there may be seats for Representatives, Governors, state legislators &c, all in the same election.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I'm not imagining anything, I'm trying to interpret the text of this answer. Should I understand what you're saying is that the "elections happen on different dates" requirement only means "regular" elections, and special elections don't count as "elections"? Well that's fine then. But do note that in the next paragraph the answer then goes on to talk about "regular elections", which you just said don't exist. So, if you have a better phrasing, I'd suggest you make an edit.

Comment: It does not appear that the Constitution prevents the Senate from changing classes as long as they don't violate the 'equal and staggered' part required in the Constitution.  Running each state Senator seperately appears to be just a Senate rule

Comment: @ilkkachu the constitution does not directly forbid elections for different classes of senators from occurring on the same day.  Rather, it specifies that the terms of different classes of senators end in different years.  Federal law in turn specifies when an election takes place to fill the seat of a senator whose term is expiring.  The date is a couple of months before the end of the term.  The result of these things is that the dates of the elections are in practice staggered so they occur every two years.

Comment: @BrooksNelson the constitution specifies that a senator's term of office is six years, except for the first batch of senators, some of whose terms were two or four years to set up the current system.  To reassign classes now, a senator's term would have to be lengthened or shortened, which would be contrary to the constitution.

Comment: @phoog Terms for Senators are shortened on a regular basis due vacancies and susequent special elections.  It seems that changing classes so two Senators were elected from the same state at the same time, with 6 year terms going forward, would just be using an already existing procedure and wouldn't violate the Constitution.

Comment: @BrooksNelson that's not the same as changing the term; it's filling a vacancy for the remainder of the fixed six-year term.  The six-year term remains.

Comment: @phoog But it does change the term when there is a special election, that Senator elected not with their class will have a different term than the rest and won't be for 6 years.  The same if you changed classes it would only be for one term.  The 6 year terms would still be the same going forward.

Comment: If elected in a special election you only serve the remainder of the term.  This is already in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

### No,

[Article I Section 3 of the United States Constitution](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articlei) mandates the seats of the three class of Senators **to be vacated at the expiration of the 2nd, 4th and 6th years *respectively***. Elections are to be held to choose one third of the Senators “every second year“.

> The seats of the Senators of the first class shall be vacated at the expiration of the second year, of the second class at the expiration of the fourth year, and the third class at the expiration of the sixth year, so that one third may be chosen every second year;

So, unless there are vacancies in the Senate (see special election procedure [outlined in the 17th Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxvii)), elections for the three different classes of Senators are mandated by the Constitution to be held every two years.

Comment: Does the constitution also state that the two senators of a given state need to be in different classes? If not, senators for a single state could still be elected simultaneously. Who or what determined the class, anyway?

Comment: @Chieron the classes were offset during the first sessions when the country was formed, and have been staggered ever since.

Comment: @Chieron, according to the [Senate's own FAQ](https://www.senate.gov/general/common/generic/NewCongress_faq.htm#class_assignments), cited from the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classes_of_United_States_Senators#cite_note-SenateFAQ-2), "In the first Senate, on May 15, 1789, the total body was divided into three groups, being sure that no state had both senators in a single group, [...]", and "When new states are added, the number in each group is kept as even as possible[.]"

Comment: @Chieron: Note also that if all states elected both their senators at the same time, the classes would not necessarily be divided "as equally as may be into three Classes."  For example, if there were 17 states in Class 1, 17 in Class 2, and 16 in Class 3, then you'd have a 34-34-32 split, which is "less equal" than the current 34-33-33 split.

Comment: (My quote is from Article I, Section 3 of the Constitution — should have made that clearer.)

Comment: If it was only a Senate rule though and not specified in the Constitution then it would seem the Senate, or possibly even a state, could reassign their Senators to the same class as long as they didn't violate the 'as equally as may be' section of the Constitution.  Which if they could do that, does anything prevent the candidates be run in the same race?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - When there were 49 states, we had 33, 33, and 32. Adding both from the same state to Class III would not change the current 50 state configuration of two with 33 and one with 34 that you'd get by adding one to the third class and one to one of the others. Don't know why you'd want to go that route, but "keeping it even" does not necessarily exclude the possibility of adding two from a state to a single class. Is there anything explicit that you are aware of, other than common sense, that would prevent this?

Comment: @BrooksNelson reassigning an existing seat to a different class would require lengthening or shortening the senator's term, for which there is no provision in the constitution (unlike the shorter terms of 2/3 of the first senators elected).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet:  You could certainly have a situation where a state has both its senators added to the same class upon joining;   I don't *think* that would be unconstitutional.  My point was that the system wouldn't work if *all* states elected both their senators in the same class, since then all classes would have to contain an even number of senators, and so the "uneven" classes would differ by at least 2 (rather than 1).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I wasn't disputing anything you said, fyi, just wondering if you were aware of an explicit prohibition on it, since the opportunity to "evenly" add two to the same state would arise in the middle occurrence of every three-state addition cycle (2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th, 14th, .... 50th state added), which also assumes states are added and Senate seats allocated one at a time.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet it could be argued that "as equally as may be" implies that no state should have two senators in the same class, and precedent certainly supports that reading.  It is not, however, explicit in the constitution.

Comment: @Panda I don't think your answer matches the headline. The answer seems to be "Yes, but only in special elections, never in a regularly-scheduled one" rather than a flat "No."